# User needs to shade cells which are protected

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a google sheet and have set up protections that restrict users to checking/unchecking a single cell. When they check or uncheck the cell, it shades data found in the same sheet. ie. numbers >90% shade dark green. numbers >80% shade light green. etc.

This, of course, works fine on my end because I don't have any protections in place for myself. However, I just realized that the users can't use the checkbox to shade cells that are protected. They are able to check/uncheck but the code in onEdit won't shade for them like it does for me.

When I first made the doc, I had set it up for conditional formatting so it would take care of it automatically. However, this made the sheets slow down as it could be shading anywhere from 50 to 300 cells in a page. (Each page has a different number of cells.) I could go back to this if I have to. If there's a way to speed that up, I'm all ears.

However, I'm hoping someone out there can help a noob figure out how to protect the cell so the user can't edit it but let the shading work as described in the first paragraph.

Thoughts?

Sandi

Edited:

Here's the code that is activated through onEdit when a user checks the "shade" cell: (I'm sure there's a better way to write the code...but still learning and kind of hacking my way through...)

```
function shadeYearByYear(){
updateValuesFromSheet();
updateScale();
ss.toast('Shading in progress. Please be patient. This will take a minute.');
numRows=currentSheet.getRange("A5").getValue();
range=currentSheet.getRange(17, 6, numRows+1, 14);
range.setBackground(null);
rangeValues=range.getValues();

for (var r=0; r<numRows+1; r++){
  for (var c=0; c<14; c++){
    if(rangeValues[r][c]>=lowerE){
      currentSheet.getRange(r+17, c+6, 1, 1).setBackground(scaleE);
    }else if(rangeValues[r][c]>=lowerP){
      currentSheet.getRange(r+17, c+6, 1, 1).setBackground(scaleP);
    }else if(rangeValues[r][c]>=lowerS){
      currentSheet.getRange(r+17, c+6, 1, 1).setBackground(scaleS);
    }else if(rangeValues[r][c]>=lowerB){
      currentSheet.getRange(r+17, c+6, 1, 1).setBackground(scaleB);
    }else if(rangeValues[r][c]>=0){
      currentSheet.getRange(r+17, c+6, 1, 1).setBackground(scaleL);
    }
  }
}
rangeHeaders=currentSheet.getRange(17, 2, numRows+1, 1);
rangeHeadersValues=rangeHeaders.getValues();
for(var r=0; r<numRows; r++){
  if (rangeHeadersValues[r][0]==="H"){
    currentSheet.getRange(r+17, 6, 1, 14).setBackground(headerShade);
  }else if(rangeHeadersValues[r][0]==="AVG"){
    currentSheet.getRange(r+18,6, 1, 14).setBackground(null);
  }
  }
}
```

Here is the code used to protect the sheet when creating I create it. range is the cell that contains the checkbox users need to toggle shading.

function protectSheet1(sheetName, range){

```
 var protection = sheetName.protect();
    var range1a = sheetName.getRange(range);
    protection.setUnprotectedRanges([range1a]);
    protection.addEditor("Myemailaddress");
    protection.addEditor("anotheremailaddress");
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if(protection.canDomainEdit()){
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }   
}
```

Edit #2: Using an installable trigger worked but I am having trouble installing it on the copies. (I know an installable trigger doesn't copy when copying the template) When I use the code below when creating the copies from my template, it just creates the trigger in the template file rather than into the new file.

Manually creating an installable trigger worked. However, I still run into a problem. Since I am using GAS to generate copies of the spreadsheets from the main template, it obviously won't copy the trigger as well.  I added the following code but it installs it in the file I'm working from rather than the copy of the file I am making.

```
schoolGradeID=DriveApp.getFileById(gradeTemplateID).makeCopy(fileName, schoolFolder).setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT).getId(); newDoc=SpreadsheetApp.openById(schoolGradeID);
        
newDoc.getSheetByName("Blank").getRange("A1").setValue(schoolArray[s]);
ScriptApp.newTrigger('shadeCells')
   .forSpreadsheet(newDoc)
   .onEdit()
   .create();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far and could show your existing code?

Comment: I have updated my original post to include the code. Everything works perfectly when I am logged in as me as my email address is the first one included in .addEditor. When another user from my domain, who is setup as an editor but only has the ability to edit the checkbox range, this user can check the checkbox but the shading doesn't occur. It claims that they are trying to edit a protected range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### User can shade protected cells if the `onEdit` trigger is of [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) type and has been set-up by you

- An installable trigger runs always on behalf of the user who installed it
- Even if the user does not have edit permission to a certain range, but is able to check a checkbox that would fire the trigger - the installable trigger will edit the protected range on your behalf
- To set-up an installable trigger you need to follow the steps of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually):

[image]

- Note that a function that is bound to an installable trigger is not allowed to be called `onEdit`
- If you bind your function `shadeYearByYear` directly to an installable trigger - this will work

Simple sample:

```js
//bind to this function an installable onEdit trigger
function shadeYearByYear(e){
  var currentSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var checkBoxColumn = "SPECIFY THE NUMBER OF THE CHECKBOX COLUMN"
  if (e.range.getColumn() == checkBoxColumn && e.value == "TRUE"){
    currentSheet.getRange(17, 6, 1, 14).setBackground('red');
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to create the installable trigger in a test file (Thank you!) and it worked in the test file. However, I can't get my master file to create the trigger when making copies. (See edit #2 in my notes). It just keeps creating the trigger in the master file.

Comment: In this case it is better to create the installable trigger programmatically rather than manually as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically). However, you will need to run the function to install the trigger once for every spreadsheet copy - because you need to authorize the trigger to run under your name.

Comment: Yep. That's what I figured out earlier today.  It'll be a pain in the butt because I have to run it for about 150 files but at least I'll only have to do it once.